# Convert a PNG image with a cHRM chunk using ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, graphicsmagick

The [PNG Browser Color-Correction Test Page](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/png-colortest.html) offers some PNG images that swap color channels using an embedded ICC color profile or a `cHRM` chunk. This image 
is a copy of `ArcTriomphe-cHRM-red-blue-swap.png`:

[image: ArcTriomphe-cHRM-red-blue-swap.png]

Basic conversion of the images with swapped channels using ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick),

```
convert ArcTriomphe-cHRM-red-blue-swap.png ArcTriomphe-cHRM-red-blue-swap.ppm
```

results in a blue version of the original, which is not what we want.

For the PNG images with an embedded ICC profile, it is possible to obtain a correctly colored output image by applying an sRGB color profile:

```
convert ArcTriomphe-iCCP-red-blue-swap.png -profile sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc ArcTriomphe-iCCP-red-blue-swap.ppm
```

However, this doesn't work for the PNG images with the `cHRM` chunk.

1. Why is ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick only applying the built-in color profile when I apply another profile myself?
2. Why will this not work for the `cHRM` PNG?

Comment: I think this is one for Glenn @Glenn-Randers-Pehrson

Comment: I suppose it's for me.  cHRM-to-profile isn't implemented.  It could be, using the approach taken by mozilla, in image/decoders/nsPNGDecoder.cpp (I think the code originally comes from littlecms).

Comment: [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/401) and [GraphicsMagick](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/bugs/414/) bugs reported.